# How to access full asset_url path in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I call render a view from the controller, then `asset_url('file.png')` returns the entire url, aka `http://www.example.com/assets/file.png`. However, if I try to render the view from anything outside of the controller, such as a service or a custom method defined in `lib/`, then the `asset_url('file.png')` just simply returns `/assets/file.png`.

It seems that the full URL for `asset_url` is only accessible when the controller is rendering a view, and that's it. Is there anything I can set so that `asset_url` will always return the full path? Or do I need to go in and manually convert 200+ `asset_url` links in my app?

View:

```
#app/views/path/to/view.html.erb
asset_url('file.png')
```

Rendering the view from controller:

```
html = render_to_string template: '/path/to/view', layout: false, locals: {report: @report}
```

Results:

```
http://www.example.com/assets/file.png
```

Rendering the view from a service or custom method:

```
# create an instance of ActionView, so we can use the render method outside of a controller
av = ActionView::Base.new()
av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths

# need these in case your view constructs any links or references any helper methods.
av.class_eval do
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    include ApplicationHelper
end
html = av.render template: '/path/to/view', layout: false, locals: {report: @report}
```

Results (missing domain):

```
/assets/file.png
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue on the github rails page, you might get an explanation there

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `asset_url` within my views, I am now using a custom method called `custom_asset_url`, which checks to see if `asset_url` has the full URL in it. If not, it puts it in there and returns it.

```
  def custom_asset_url(asset)
    # This was defined because if you call asset_url outside of a controller, then the host doesn't 
    # render, therefore it just displays /assets/ instead of http://www.example.com/assets (which breaks PDF generation).

    url = asset_url(asset)
    if !url.include? "http"
      if Rails.env.production?
        url = "https://prod-url#{url}"
      else
        url = "http://dev-url:3000#{url}"
      end
    end
    return url
  end
```

Until I can figure out why `asset_url` is nil when called from outside of a controller, this is the workaround method.